# What does action mean for scheduled events in python?

Tags: python, scheduler

I have been trying to run a timer to increase a counter which is used by a class to print out different stuff from a JSON file.

I sort of had something working, but it was always running on top of my cmd prompt and main file so nothing else would work while it was running.

Then I started reading up on schedules and threading and now I'm having a bit of an issue with it. Here is what I have:

```
import time
import sched

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

counter = 0

def addCount(counter):
    counter = counter + 1

def tick():
    print time.time()
    s.enter(5, 0, addCount, counter)
    s.run()
    print time.time()
    print counter

tick()
```

I want it to run the `addCount` as the action, but if I use counter as an argument then it returns that it needs to be a sequence not an int. Would I change `counter` to `counter.append(1)` to add 1 to the counter? Or how would I get `addCount` to run as a scheduled task every 5 seconds?

Also if I set the priority to 0 then it should run first and under everything else correct, or am I just way off on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last argument is a *sequence of arguments* to be passed to your function. `counter` is not a sequence, but you can make it one by wrapping it in a tuple:

```
s.enter(5, 0, addCount, (counter,))
```

From the [`scheduler.enterabs()` method documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler.enterabs):

> Executing the event means executing `action(*argument)`. *argument* must be a sequence holding the parameters for *action*.

Lower `priority` values indeed mean higher precedence; `0` goes before `1`, etc.

This isn't clearly documented in the library documentation; I had to go to the [module source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/sched.py) for that; the docstring states:

> As in UNIX, lower priority numbers mean higher priority; in this
>   way the queue can be maintained as a priority queue.

Note that your `addCount()` function won't work as written; `counter` is just a local, so you'll be incrementing `0` to `1` each and every time. You'd have to use a global instead:

```
counter = 0

def addCount():
    global counter
    counter = counter + 1
```

No argument is then passed in, so make `argument` an empty tuple:

```
def tick():
    print time.time()
    s.enter(5, 0, addCount, ())
    s.run()
    print time.time()
    print counter
```

Demo:

```
>>> import time
>>> import sched
>>> s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
>>> counter = 0
>>> def addCount():
...     global counter
...     counter = counter + 1
... 
>>> def tick():
...     print time.time()
...     s.enter(5, 0, addCount, ())
...     s.run()
...     print time.time()
...     print counter
... 
>>> tick()
1422090645.65
1422090650.65
1
```

Comment: That did a whole lot to explain something I've been trying to figure out for some time and it sort of worked. I thought that if I made it a scheduled task instead of a loop it would allow another function to run at the same time, but it instead it waits for the scheduled task to complete before moving on. Is there a way to get it to run under the other function? And thanks for your help!

Comment: Cancel that, I figured out threading. Still not doing exactly what I want it too, but it is progress. ^_^

Comment: @Illyduss: glad you figured it out! :-) Yes, `sched` doesn't magically give you concurrency, only control over when different pieces of code are being called.